# Value of model is gone when custom directive is applied to a input field

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-directive

I have an input field as such, where i apply a custom directive for validation.

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="ev.name" ischanged="{{d.EventName}}"/>
```

The directive is as such :

```
app.directive('ischanged', function () {
'use strict';
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (input) {

            if(attr.ischanged == input) {
                ctrl.$setValidity('ischanged', false);                      
            }
            else if(attr.ischanged != input)
            {                   
                ctrl.$setValidity('ischanged', true);   
            }
        });

     }

    };
});
```

The directive compares the value with another value, and sets the validity of the field accordingly. But, when i apply this directive. `{{ev.name}}` will show nothing as I enter value into it.

`{{ev.name}}`fine when I remove the directive entirely.

I realized this problem when I tried to update through http.put, it says that the one of the data is empty.

Comment: What is d.EventName?

Comment: @jbrown it's just a name of an event, a string.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do or what your issue is so I created a plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/sABrAn3MTVTwBQNDbeN7?p=preview) that contains your code.  Check it out and let me know what isn't working as you intended.

Comment: @jbrown I see an empty plunker, can you check back? Anyways, my problem is when I apply this directive, the value of $scope.ev.name seems to become empty although there are values in it. This then leads to problem with my php ( This is a page updating event name)

Comment: Refresh this page and check the plunker again.  I had pasted the wrong url in my comment

Comment: @jbrown try adding {{ev.name}} to the html, and start typing. you will see no values. but when you remove the directive it works fine

Comment: I would step through your link function.  You'll find that attr.ischanged is the name of the event that you passed in.  You're checking to see if this equals input which is the text typed in by the user.  Is that what you're really wanting to evaluate?  That the user typed in the event name?  Maybe it is and I'm just confused by the use of the term 'event'.  Maybe you don't mean it in the usual way as a javascript event.  Probably would avoid some confusion if you included your controller that shows your model.

Comment: I'm going to make the assumption that I misunderstood and what you really want to do is validate input against some event name.  If so, I've updated the plunker to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing a return statement to update the model in your directive.  I added one just to update the model if the value is valid.  You can decide how you want to handle the invalid case.

```
app.directive('ischanged', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(input) {

        if (attr.ischanged == input) {
          ctrl.$setValidity('ischanged', false);
          return input ? input : undefined;
        } else if (attr.ischanged != input) {
          ctrl.$setValidity('ischanged', true);
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Here's a working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/sABrAn3MTVTwBQNDbeN7?p=preview) that also includes some HTML changes as well so that you can see the validation working and the model updating.